# Problem with loop.last

Tags: templating, loop

In Dev mode I get the following runtime error:

```
Key "last" for array with keys "parent, index0, index, first" does not exist
```

and it highlights the line {{ not loop.last ? ' & ' }}

In Production mode the template works fine.
This is the code:

```
{# Loop through entries related to an asset #}
{% set entry = craft.entries.relatedTo(asset).orderby('title') %}
    {% for entry in entry %}
       <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
       {{ not loop.last ? ' &amp; ' }} 
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add `.all()` to the end of your `craft.entries` element query, which will execute it and return the results as a simple array:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.relatedTo(asset).orderBy('title').all() %}
{% for entry in entry %}
   <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
   {{ not loop.last ? ' &amp; ' }} 
{% endfor %}
```

The reason why you're getting the error without `.all()` is that the `loop.last` variable is only added to the Twig context within a `{% for %}` loop if *Twig can reliably tell how many things it's looping over*. Looping on element queries (i.e. the thing returned by `craft.entries`) directly is discouraged for a number of reasons, this gotcha being one of them.

Comment: Thanks Mats, This was a template in a Craft 2 site that I upgraded to Craft 4 and I missed the significance of .all() in this query as it was all working fine in production mode. It was as only when testing something else in Dev mode it showed up. I expected this sort of thing to show up in the 'Depreciation Warnings'